# How do I delete for every second index on a mesh line in Geo Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

So i have an issue in blender's geo nodes where I am not able to delete for every second index on the mesh line.

I tried using a snapping math node set to 2, but that doesnt seem to work. I want to skip over 1 index then delete the next:

[image]

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is the modulo node.

Comment: Do you want to delete the vertices, leaving yourself with disconnected points, or dissolve the vertices, leaving the remainder connected by edges?

Comment: and is it really by index or regularly along the mesh line?

Comment: Maybe just spawn a new line with double the offset and half the points? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: No its ok, a math node set to truncated modulo was the answer, thanks for all the help